# Angular `mat-table` two-way binding

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-table, two-way-binding

I have a binding issue with **mat-checkbox** inside a **mat-table**.
The `dataSource` of the table is a basic array of objects and each object has a selected `boolean` property.
For some reason, the two way binding is not working and selected always return false when the click event is fired.

The code is like this:

**app.component.ts**

```js
   clients: Client[] = [
       { id: 1, name: `Client`, disabled: true, selected: false },
   ];

   onClientClick(client: Client) {
       console.log(client) // selected here is false
   }
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="clients">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="client-name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>header</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let client">
            <mat-checkbox (click)="onClientClick(client)" [(ngModel)]="client.selected" [disabled]="client.disabled">
                {{ client.name }}
            </mat-checkbox>
        </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsClients"></tr>
</table>
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Create DataSource of type MatTableDataSource.

`clients= new MatTableDataSource<any>([{ id: 1, name: 'Client', disabled: true, selected: false }]);`

And then,

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="clients">
<ng-container matColumnDef="client-name">
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>header</th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let client">
    <mat-checkbox (click)="onClientClick(client)"
    [disabled]="client.disabled" [checked]="client.selected">
    {{ client.name }}
    </mat-checkbox>
</td>
</ng-container>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsClients"></tr>
```